# Reads only alphabetic chars with fscanf

Tags: c

Hello i have simply function to read from file

```
while(fscanf(fp," %255[a-zA-Z]",test) == 1)
{
    puste = 1;
    push(&drzewo,test);
}
```

It should read only words which contains only alphabetic characters and that works great.  When I have for example a single number in my file my while loop quits; how should I change it?

Comment: Right now it reads only alphabetic characters. What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: what you want exactelly read all kind of word? even that word contains non alphabetic characters?

Comment: As I understand it, he wants it to just skip everything else. You'll have to take out fscanf from the while condition and put that test inside of your loop, taking something else as your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it stops, since the `fscanf()` call will fail to do the conversion you're requiring, and thus return 0. What would you expect it to do?

It's often better to read whole lines using `fgets()`, and then parse them "manually", that way it's easy to just do nothing and read another line if the desired data is not found.